# Persistent class does not seem to have been enhanced.You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output."

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I'm using Maven to build a Google appengine project.
My pom.xml includes the necessary datanucleus enhance pulgin

```
<build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy
                                file="${project.basedir}/src/main/localjars/ccavutil.jar"
                                todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.google.guava:guava</exclude> <!-- avoid android version -->
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/validators/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-maven</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <version>3.5</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requirePluginVersions>
                                <message>Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!</message>
                                <banLatest>true</banLatest>
                                <banRelease>true</banRelease>
                                <phases>clean,deploy,verify,appengine:run,appengine:deploy,appengine:update,appengine:devappaserver,site</phases>
                            </requirePluginVersions>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <api>JDO</api>
                <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

After running the app, when I try to create a user its giving me this error:

Problem accessing /jsp/reg.jsp. Reason:

```
Persistent class "Class com.dhiti.care.server.datastore.DbUser does not seem to have been enhanced.  You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output." has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.
```

Caused by:

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Persistent class "Class com.dhiti.care.server.datastore.DbUser does not seem to have been enhanced.  You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for errors in the output." has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:375)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:230)
    at com.dhiti.care.server.DbUserJdoDAO.getUId(DbUserJdoDAO.java:176)
    at com.dhiti.care.server.DbUserJdoDAO.registerUser(DbUserJdoDAO.java:330)
    at com.dhiti.care.server.handler.RegisterHandler.execute(RegisterHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.reg_jsp._jspService(reg_jsp.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:21)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
    at com.dhiti.care.server.servlets.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace
```

Comment: so perhaps you should do what it says ... look for errors in when you enhanced it. You did enhance it?!

Comment: I ran this `mvn appengine:enhance -X`, Its prints the error stack trace:

Standard error from the DataNucleus tool + org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer :
[ERROR] --------------------
[ERROR] Error: Could not find or load main class org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer

--followed by the stack trace
I searched for above error, but didnt find any luck..

Comment: Luck doesn't come into software. It is down to what you specify. If it can't find the enhancer class then you have either not put it in the CLASSPATH or you have specified it wrong

Answer (score 0):

The new [Cloud SDK-based Maven plugin does not support Datanucleus enhancement](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-maven#notable_differences) of any type. You will have to configure the 3rd party Datanucleus Maven plugin separately. Here are the instructions for [JDO](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2) and [JPA](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2). If you check out the link, you will see that you are missing some dependencies in your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You got to do following things to get your classes ENHANCED in Maven with Cloud SDK support:

1. Define all necessary Datanucleus jars in **dependencies** section including the Enhancer dependency.

```html
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.jar.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.orm/datanucleus-appengine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>${datanucleus.jar.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Add plugin to **plugins** section:

```html
                  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <api>JDO</api>
                        <mappingIncludes>com/example/dataModels/*.class</mappingIncludes>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <fork>false</fork>
                        <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>                      
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enhance</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                            <version>${datanucleus.jar.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

3. Compile your code

   **$mvn compile**
4. now Enhance your compiled classes:

   **$mvn datanucleus:enhance**

This must enhance your classes for sure.